# Can I load text / flat json from datatable.net?

Tags: datatables

Hi i have been using datatables but have not tried loading data view pure json object.

I always use sAjax source so it always point to a url.

My question is how to pass a json object directyl so that it will eliminate the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Json.parse and add the values in a loop:

```
$(function() {
  json = '{ "employees" : [' +
    '{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },' +
    '{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },' +
    '{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" } ]}';

  parsedJson= JSON.parse(json);
  var otable = $("#datatable").dataTable();

  //Forgot to clear the table first
  otable.fnClearTable();

  $.each(parsedJson.employees, function(key, value) {
    otable.dataTable().fnAddData([
      value.firstName,
      value.lastName,
    ]);
  })

});
```

[Here's a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/weauG5h5vH0INHOELASD?p=preview)