# Json ajax data on a datatable Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, datatables

I am new to jquery. i have a datatable with data at the loading time. after searching data i need to remove that data from the datatable and display the searched data on that table. i cleared the datatable by using

```
app.common.genericAjaxCall("POST", '\getGroupsajax=true"', data, function(data) {

                dataGrid = dataGrid.fnClearTable();
                dataGrid = $('#dataGrid').dataTable().fnAddData(data);
                alert('hidata');
            }
```

but it is not giving the correct result.

My json output is:

```
Object  { "aaData" : [{"id":37,"attemptId":1,"name":"Group1","emailIds":null,"type":"Forward","status":1,"scheduleDate":"03/10/2014 21:50 PM","sheduledBy":null,"startDate":null,"endDate":null,"action":0}]}
```

there are more than one results on this array.
Then i need to display the data. data get from a json ajax call. How to fix this. greatly appreciate your help

Comment: What lib or framework are you using ?

Comment: Can you show us some of the json data you get from your ajax? You can not simply add JSON Data with fnAddData. You should JSON.parse(data) first. Look at this Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924803/can-i-load-text-flat-json-from-datatable-net/21936117#21936117

Comment: i tried with it. but it gives an Object type. not converting. gives an exception 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aoData' of null '

Answer (score 0):

Works for me using this initilisation:

```
  json = '{ "aaData" : [{"id":37,"attemptId":1,"name":"Group1","emailIds":null,"type":"Forward","status":1,"scheduleDate":"03/10/2014 21:50 PM","sheduledBy":null,"startDate":null,"endDate":null,"action":0}]}';

  parsedJson= JSON.parse(json);
  var otable = $("#datatable").dataTable();

  otable.fnClearTable();

  $.each(parsedJson.aaData, function(key, value) {
    otable.dataTable().fnAddData([
      value.id,
      value.attemptId,
      value.name,
      value.emailIds,
      value.type,
      value.status,
      value.scheduleDate,
      value.sheduledBy,
      value.startDate,
      value.endDate,
      value.action,
    ]);
  })
```

If OBJECT is realy some text of your output, remove it:-)

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tklLh7LNPX6tmc4TbuzZ?p=preview)